# difference between "used to" and "have in the past"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is there any difference in meaning between:

"I have smoked in the past, but I don't smoke now" and

"I used to smoke but I don't smoke now"?

Comment: I think you know the difference. One goes to ongoingness of the action and the other is merely in the past without specifying when.

Comment: What do you mean by "ongoingness of the action?" In both cases I don't smoke anymore.

Comment: 'I used to smoke' means you habitually or regularly smoked (did it on an ongoing basis); 'I have smoked' says nothing about how many times you did it.

Comment: Here in the States, I see no difference between the two. I see both statements as indicating continuous action in the past. Over here, one doesn't say they have smoked if you smoke once or twice.

Comment: In the UK 'I have smoked pot', could mean 'I took a puff on a joint at a party in 1972, and never again', but 'I used to smoke pot' could mean 'I don't remember much about the eighties'. I do not know to which category Bill Clinton belongs.

Comment: "I have stood in the sea" could be true either if I stood in the sea once in my life or I did it every day when I lived in Margate; 'I used to stand in the sea daily when I lived in Margate' is more informative.

Comment: I agree to @FeliniusRex. I can't see any difference. Upvoted.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey " have smoked' says nothing about how many times you did it." So smoking was habitual....

Comment: @FeliniusRex interesting! Do you mean that you wouldn't say specifically 'I have smoked' if you weren't "a smoker" at one point, or more generally that you would generally use 'I have...' for any habitual action? — e.g. if someone said "I was pretty good at bowling; I have scored 300 in the past, but I don't play now" vs "I was pretty good at bowling; I used to score 300, but I don't play now", I would definitely assume the first sentence is a one-off and the second is a regular occurrence. Would you use them interchangeably in the US?

Comment: @anotherdave Specifically smoking -- I think it must be the addictive, habitual nature of smoking that drives this. People understand you don't smoke once or twice. To say that you have smoked (in the past) means that you were *smoking* in the past, that is, you habitually smoked. On the other hand, you can say "Yes, I have played pool" without people thinking that you live in the pool hall. :)

Comment: @FeliniusRex ah cool, yeah that makes sense. Good point that smoking by its nature is habitual. Makes for a more blurry question from the OP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have smoked in the past, but I don't smoke now - it suggests that I have smoked on a few occasions in the past but I don't smoke now

I used to smoke but I don't smoke now - It leans more towards the meaning that I used to smoke on a regular basis but I don't smoke now.Just a slight difference

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding they contradict each other in terms of telling the reader when and how many.

They are very much alike and seen to have the same meaning but I break things down like this:

As if answering a question "Do you smoke?"

I **used to smoke**. Now I do not.
add words to see if it is correct.
I used to smoke[A few here and there]. Now I do not.

As if you are answering a question. "Are you a smoker?"
I **have smoked** in the past. Now I do not.
I have smoked [A few here and there] in the past. Now I do not.

In both cases, you do not smoke anymore but...
One is saying you smoked often,
One is saying you didn't smoke a specific amount

Comment: Are you a native speaker, Monica? I don't understand your answer, What do you mean by: "they contradict eachother"? Because your definitions are exactly the same: "I used to smoke a few here and there, now I do not" and "I have smoked a few here and there, now I do not". What is the difference?